# What is the scope of an unassigned object within a function? And when will the object gets disposed/garbage collected?

Tags: c#

I would like to know when the object initialized inside a method gets disposed.
My assumption is when the scope of the function ends.

```
public void foo() {
 new Object1().SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: At the end of the method.

Comment: That's right. And it will be collected when the GC thinks it's time to collect. (always assuming `SomeMethod` does not put `this` into some other surviving object).

Comment: Nothing ever gets disposed unless you use the `using` statement or call Dispose() explicitly.  Maybe you meant "collected" instead of "disposed"?  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034) for the gritty details.  So not at the end of the method.